# Unable to perform get text operation

Tags: python, pywinauto

Getting 'ElementNotFoundError' when I tried to read a text from the below (Cropped image for reference).

[image]

**code:**

```
app = Application(backend='uia').start(
    r"cmd.exe /c start AppName",
    create_new_console=True,
    wait_for_idle=False)
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(title_re="AppName", found_index=0, timeout=10).AppName  
print(app.print_control_identifiers())
print(app.child_window(title="foo boo e", control_type="Text",
                                              found_index=0).wrapper_object().window_text())
```

**Expected Output:**

```
All control identifiers hierarchy.
foo boo e
```

**Actual Output:**

```
 Static - 'foo boo e'    (L603, T234, R728, B249)
    ['foo boo eStatic', 'foo boo e', 'Static54']
    child_window(title="foo boo e", control_type="Text")

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python3108\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 250, in __resolve_control
    ctrl = wait_until_passes(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python3108\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 458, in wait_until_passes
    raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\foo\boo\test.py", line 171, in <module>
    print(test.pwa_gettextt("Pick a Date & Time", "Text", None, 10))
  File "C:\Users\foo\boo\test.py", line 49, in pwa_gettextt
    found_index=index).wrapper_object().window_text()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python3108\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 267, in wrapper_object
    ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python3108\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 261, in __resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python3108\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 436, in wait_until_passes
    func_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python3108\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 222, in __get_ctrl
    ctrl = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**ctrl_criteria))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python3108\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 84, in find_element
    elements = find_elements(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python3108\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 328, in find_elements
    raise ElementNotFoundError("found_index is specified as {0}, but {1} window/s found".format(
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: found_index is specified as 0, but 0 window/s found

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Observation:**

While I tried to identity object using "pywinauto recorder", I  found that it is pointing it out to the green color empty area when I hover the mouse in blurred text with a left out char 'e'. I am not sure how to handle these type of challenge in pywinato. Please help.

Note: print control identifier method properly printed the object of text that I wanted. Reference can be seen above.

Comment: Please post the full error text in the future. `ElementNotFoundError` usually points to the search criteria that don't match with any element.

Comment: Ah, well, the confusion was added when you named window specification for "AppName" to `app` object. `Application` object wraps the process only (with process ID or PID). It's better to name it `main_win = app.AppName` where `app` is instance of `Application`. Also probably application title is not found which should be pointed in the error text. Because it's a 2-level search. Full error text is always important.

Comment: Why do you create two Application objects?

Comment: @vasily-v-ryabov: Have added the full error message as requested! 
This error when I dont pass any index at all. "pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title': 'foo boo e', 'auto_id': None, 'control_type': 'Text', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo - 'AppName', ApplicationFrameWindow, 3803208>, 'backend': 'uia'}"

Comment: @VasilyRyabov: Any advise?

Comment: Please try to remove `found_index=0` from the second level of search. If you are not lucky, please `print([w.window_text() for w in Application(backend='uia').connect(title_re="AppName", found_index=0, timeout=10).windows()])` to see if there are 2 top level windows. Also try different `found_index` for the `connect` params.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov: Thanks for the recommendations . The above prints a single window name (Example: ['AppName']) only. Secondly, tried with different indexes from 0 to 5 but apparently none worked in favour yet.

Comment: Well, please try dumping `.children()` (means immediate children) for next level. Try `.window_text()` and `.control_type()` for each child element like it was dumped for top level window in my previous comment. Maybe there is a little difference in texts. Try to do exact comparison of mentioned properties with your constant strings in the script.